# Waypoints JS Move Main Menu to Fixed Header on Scroll Up

Tags: javascript, jquery-waypoints

I have a main header (#top-bar) with page navigation and a sub-navigation bar (#category-bar) with links to sections on the page. The sub-navigation bar loads on the bottom of the screen, then as the user scrolls down the sub-navigation bar pushes the fixed position main header off screen by changing it to absolute position. The sub-navigation bar becomes fixed to the top. This all works fine with waypoints js triggering different position states for the bars.

I now need to have the main header reappear on scroll up. Here is my javascript so far, though it does not effect the header on scroll up:

```
function moveHeader() {
var topBar = '#top-bar',
var stickyElement = jQuery('#category-bar');
var bottomBarOffset = stickyElement.offset();
var topOffset = jQuery(topBar).offset().top; //get the offset top of the element


jQuery(stickyElement).waypoint({
    handler: function(direction) {
    if (direction === 'down') {
        jQuery(topBar).css({ position: 'absolute', top: bottomBarOffset.top - jQuery(topBar).outerHeight() });
    }
    else {
        jQuery(topBar).attr('style', '');       
    }
    },
    offset: topBarHeight - 1,
});

jQuery(topBar).waypoint({
    handler: function(direction) {
    if (direction === 'up') {
        jQuery(this.element).addClass('pin');
    }
    else {
        jQuery(this.element).removeClass('pin');
    }
    },
    offset: topOffset - jQuery(window).scrollTop() - 100,  //attempt to trigger main header pushed off screen top
});
}
```

I have tried different calculations to trigger the #top-bar without any luck. Does anyone have advice for the calculation or different approach for this project?

Answer (score 0):

After reading more related SO topics and some tests with waypoints js, I abandoned waypoints js for this portion of the script. I created a function for calculating the trigger point for setting the fixed header. The variable calculation constantly changed on scroll up, which caused waypoints to continually fire and create a flickering effect. This made me realize that this implementation is not the proper use for waypoints. My solution implements a simple scroll up / scroll down jQuery function after leaving the top section. In this script, it is set to fire on a 20 pixel scroll in either direction:

```
function moveHeader() {
    var topBar = '#top-bar',
    var stickyElement = '#category-bar';
    var bottomBarOffset = jQuery(stickyElement).offset();
    var topBarOffset = jQuery(topBar).offset().top;

    jQuery(stickyElement).waypoint({
        handler: function(direction) {
        if (direction === 'down') {
            jQuery(topBar).css({ position: 'absolute', top: bottomBarOffset.top - jQuery(topBar).outerHeight() });
        }
        else {
            jQuery(topBar).attr('style', '');       
        }
        },
        offset: topBarHeight - 1,
    });

    jQuery(function(){
        var lastScrollTop = 0;
        var scrollDistance = 20;
        if (jQuery('body').hasClass('page-template-page-sections-menu')) {
        jQuery(window).scroll(function(event){
            var st = jQuery(this).scrollTop();
            if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= scrollDistance)
                return;
            if (st > lastScrollTop && st > windowHeight && jQuery('body').hasClass('scroll-up'))
            {
                // downscroll code
                jQuery('body').addClass('scroll-dn');
                jQuery('body').removeClass('scroll-up');
                jQuery(stickyElement).attr('style', '');        
            } else if (st < lastScrollTop && st > windowHeight)
            {
                // upscroll code
                jQuery('body').addClass('scroll-up');
                jQuery('body').removeClass('scroll-dn');
                jQuery(topBar).attr('style', '');       
                jQuery(stickyElement).attr('style', '');        
            } else if (st < lastScrollTop && st < windowMinusTop)
            {
                // upscroll and first section (window height from top of document)
                jQuery(stickyElement).css({ 'z-index': '0' });
                jQuery('body').removeClass('scroll-up scroll-dn');
            }
                lastScrollTop = st;
        });
        };
    });
}
```

This solution achieves what my client needs, though I am open to any further improvements.